# How to echo variable before declaration? php

Tags: php, variables, echo

I need to echo a var in a page but the value is declared later after being included in the page.

Is there any way to echo a var before I declare it? or some way to include the page withought running any of the code and just getting the var?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain a bit more the problem you're trying to solve. It might also be rewarding to look up the docs for the [ob_start function](http://php.net/ob_start).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No language is obviously able to output a value, before it exists.

Comment: Any language is able to do so, but it will print null, undefined or void depending on their 'not declared' error definition.

Comment: @markcial: I said "value". If a variable doesn't contain any value (or is not even defined), it will output "nothing", what may be something like "undefined", or "null". Thats more or less a placeholder for missing values, but can not get treated as a value.

Comment: sometimes the simplest answer is the best :D

Comment: i was simply joking :) anyways anything that has a meaning, or representation is a value, so i consider undefined, null or void values, although their representation is unsafe and can not be handled without unexpected behaviours.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do something like..

```
echo $var;

$var = "Hello world";
```

Then the answer is no. PHP is an interpreted language which runs downwards, not every which way.

Comment: ok, just wanted to make sure.
I seem to recall reading that php runs the entire code before output....
Thanks :) +1

Comment: @Tom, it does, and you can use functions and classes before defining them, but not variables... It's an imperative language after all.

Comment: @Tom I think you're thinking about `debug_backtrace()` which does read backwards through the tree.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest, best and most sensible option is to fix your logic so everything happens in a logical order.

Failing that. Store your data in a variable instead of outputting it. Include a placeholder where you want the variable to be. Then do a search and replace on that placeholder once you have the data you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can build a template-like solution. Put something like `##var##` in the page, use `ob_start()` at the beginning of the page, define your `$var` whereever, then, at the end of the page, use `echo str_replace('##var##', $var, ob_get_clean());`.

---

Example:

```
<?php ob_start() ?>
<p>##test##</p>
<?php $test = "this is a test paragraph" ?>
<?php echo str_replace("##test##", $test, ob_get_clean()) ?>
```

Check out [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/ob_start), and [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/ob_get_clean).

Comment: 0.o
now im lost :)
my php is limited to if/else, includes, and echo  haha
but thanks

Comment: The problem is that you, of course, can't use variables before defining them. A workaround is to render the whole page, put placeholders in the page, then replace these placeholders with the value of your variable _after_ the variable is defined, at the end of the script.

Comment: Updated the answer with an example and references.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to use JavaScript with PHP for this kind of echos.

```
$echo  = document.getElementById('dispaly_div').innerHTML = "$variable";
```

Answer (score 0):

**One way is to use functions.**

For example:

```
function printvar($string) {
  echo $string;
}
      
printvar("Hello World!");
```

This is tested and works.

Comment: please align your codes and describe your answer some more